# React Hook Form's register function does not work when using custom components

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form, zod

I'm refactoring some code in my app and I noticed that when I moved my input element to be its own reusable component, hook-form's register function stopped working. This can be fixed if you use the plain input element, but I would like to use my own component. Here's a stack blitz with a reproducible example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9bafks?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check what register('text') actually gives you `console.log(register("text"))` you will see that there is a `ref`. You have to make your custom inputs to forward that ref.

```
const TextInput: FC<Props> = React.forwardRef(({ error, ...props }, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> {error} </p>
      <input {...props} ref={ref}/>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue for me: `const TextInput: FC<Props> = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with custom component. I decided my problem:

```
<div {...register2("phone_code2")}>
  <PhoneCodesSelect
    onChange={(v) => setValue("phone_code2", v)}
    zIndex={6}
    handleOpen={handleOpen}
    handleClose={handleClose}
    open={open[1]}
    ind={1}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).